# Add a dynamic property to a Mongoose result with _.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I want to dynamically add a property to each object of a Mongoose result, but it won't work as expected.

```
Font.find()
.exec(function (err, fonts) {

    if(err) return res.send(err);

    _.each(fonts, function(item, i) {
        item.joined_name = item.name + item.style.replace(/\s/g, '');
        console.log(item.joined_name); // works fine
    });

    res.send(fonts); // `joined_name` property is nonexistant
});
```

Must be simple, but I can't figure out why. Alternatives are welcome!

Comment: Try to change item.joined_name to fonts[i].joined_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Mongoose documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js)** don't allow adding properties. You need to either call the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method before **`exec()`** since documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects.

From the docs:

```
Font.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

So your code should look like:

```
Font.find()
    .lean()
    .exec(function (err, fonts) {
        if(err) return res.send(err);

        _.each(fonts, function(item, i) {
            item.joined_name = item.name + item.style.replace(/\s/g, '');
            console.log(item.joined_name); // works fine
        });

        res.send(fonts);  
    });
```

or cast the returned document to a plain object:

```
Font.find()
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        var fonts = [];
        _.each(docs, function(item, i) {
            var obj = item.toObject();
            obj.joined_name = obj.name + obj.style.replace(/\s/g, '');
            console.log(obj.joined_name); 
            fonts.push(obj);
        });

        res.send(fonts); 
    });
```